# How do you read files in chunks in R

Tags: r

I have a vector called files, which has 500000 files in a directory:

```
length(files)
500000
```

I need to read files in chunks of 10000

I am not sure if this is the right syntax:

```
for(k in 1:length(files){

 for(p in seq(1, length(files), by=1000)){
   data<-readLines(files[p])
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have your loops the wrong way round

```
for(p in seq(1, length(files), by = 1000)){
  for(k in p:min(p + 1000, length(files))){

    data  <- readLines(files[p])
  }
}
```

The `min(p + 1000, length(files))` gives you a block of 1000 except when there are fewer than 1000 files remaining, in which case it gives you the number remaining.

Comment: if it is not multiple of 1000, how do we make sure we account for all of the files?

Comment: Updated answer with a solution to this problem